# How to apply styles from styles.xml to span?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to apply a custom style defined in styles.xml to part of a string in a `TextView`. I tried using `SpannableStringBuilder` with `StyleSpan`, but that doesn't seem to work. Would appreciate any pointers on this. Here's what my code looks like right now:

styles.xml

```
<style name="damn_red">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/f_red_800</item>
     <item name="android:background">@color/f_red_800</item>
     <item name="android:text">@color/f_red_800</item>
</style>
```

Activity.java

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder();
spannable.append("Some ")
         .append("text ",  new StyleSpan(R.style.damn_red), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
         .append("this is");
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
textView.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I've looked at multiple questions here but couldn't find any that would answer this. Would appreciate any pointers here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A [`StyleSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan) can set whether text is bold, italic or normal.

> Span that allows setting the style of the text it's attached to. Possible styles are: Typeface.NORMAL, Typeface.BOLD, Typeface.ITALIC and Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC.

What I think you are looking for is [`TextAppearanceSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan). From ["Styles and Themes"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes):

> One limitation with styles is that you can apply only one style to a View. In a TextView, however, you can also specify a TextAppearance attribute which functions similarly to a style...

The application is similar to what you are currently doing. If that doesn't do everything you need, take a look at the [complete list of span types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary).

Answer (score 1):

In practice the code will look like this:

```
 val boldSpan = TextAppearanceSpan(requireContext(), R.style.MyHeading6)
 nameAndAddress.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, name.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```